# UICollection View images from url

Tags: objective-c, url, ios6, uicollectionview

I have followed this tutorial to make a UICollectionView custom layout: http://skeuo.com/uicollectionview-custom-layout-tutorial#section4
I got through it and I got it working. But when I try to use it with my own pictures I cannot get them show in the app.
Here's the code to get the pictures

```
     self.albums = [NSMutableArray array];

    NSURL *urlPrefix =
        [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://raw.github.com/ShadoFlameX/PhotoCollectionView/master/Photos/"];

    NSInteger photoIndex = 0;

    for (NSInteger a = 0; a < 12; a++) {
        BHAlbum *album = [[BHAlbum alloc] init];
        album.name = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Photo Album %d",a + 1];

        NSUInteger photoCount = 1;
        for (NSInteger p = 0; p < photoCount; p++) {
            // there are up to 25 photos available to load from the code repository
            NSString *photoFilename = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"thumbnail%d.jpg",photoIndex % 25];
            NSURL *photoURL = [urlPrefix URLByAppendingPathComponent:photoFilename];
            BHPhoto *photo = [BHPhoto photoWithImageURL:photoURL];
            [album addPhoto:photo];

            photoIndex++;
        }

    [self.albums addObject:album];
}
```

So the problem comes when I change the url string to the one with my pictures. I want to use a public website for hosting images like Flickr, but I also tried Imageshak.us and postimage.org and it didn't work.
I have the photo names as it says the string: thumbnail%d.jpd so that is not the problem. Any ideas?

UPDATE:
I tried using this

```
[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.flickr.com/photos/93436974@N06/"];
```

That's the url to the gallery, but it doesn't show anything. If I can't use Flickr, is there any other websites similar that could be used?

Comment: Am I understanding you correctly: this code is working, just after you change it (to another URL) it ceases to work? Then you might want to post the changed code.

Comment: This code doesn't display images. You need to show the code where you actually show them. Also if you log photo, what does it give you?

Comment: @w.m Yes, I updated the post. When I use my url it just doesn't show the images.

Comment: @rdelmar Yes, I know. But it is actually working and showing the pictures, but the problem comes when I change the URL to other one from a gallery I've made. The one shown there is used by the person who made the tutorial mentioned above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your thumbnails you're naming them "thumbnail0.jpg" "thumbnail1.jpg" etc right? The %d means insert the number from outside the quotes here, for the code you posted it takes whichever number photo you're on and adds it into your string (up to a maximum of 25 at which point it will restart , ie photo 27 would return thumbnail2.jpg

Just quickly googling it looks like flickr doesn't keep the source file name so it wouldn't work with the code you posted. I would recommend photobucket I beilieve they keep the source file name and urls are easy to work with

Comment: The OP's code doesn't access Flickr. His URL's are valid -- if you put one in Safari, it does access an image.

Comment: That's because the ops code is the urls for the tutorial linked, he's saying when he changes them to his own urls it doesn't work and he mentioned trying to use flickr

Comment: @TyloBedo I tried photobucket but it didn't work either.. Any other ideas? or how can I check if a site keeps the source file names?

Comment: @emiliomarin currently your app is trying to pull the images from http://www.flickr.com/photos/93436974@N06/thumbnail0.jpg however if you paste that url into your browser you'll get an error because the pictures aren't at that location. If you go to photobucket or another image hosting website you have them uploaded too look for an images direct link and you'll want to use this link minus the file name. Make sure that all of your pictures have the same direct link too minus the file name, I'm certain photobucket will have the same direct links i'm not sure about others.

Comment: Just as an example [http://i216.photobucket.com/albums/cc279/tylobedo/thumbnail0.jpg](http://i216.photobucket.com/albums/cc279/tylobedo/thumbnail0.jpg) is the direct link to a photo i've uploaded to photobucket, the url you'd use is [http://i216.photobucket.com/albums/cc279/tylobedo/](http://i216.photobucket.com/albums/cc279/tylobedo/)

Comment: @TyloBedo I tried that, and I noticed that the problem is that the change the name of the picture: http://i1326.photobucket.com/albums/u643/marinemilio/thumbnail20_zps0cf5ad17.jpg So instead  of "thumbnail20.jpg" it's "thumbnail20_zps0cf5ad17.jpg" Could I just change the string of the names to show all the pictures in my album, no matter what the names are? or how could I do it?

Comment: @emiliomarin I don't think there is an easy way to just display all the photos in the album from any image hosting site. My advice would either add the photos to your app locally or if you really wanted to add them from a website you could manually add each photos url `if (photoIndex == 0) { NSURL *photoUrl= [NSURL URLWithString:@"direct link to thumbnail0"]; }`

Comment: @TyloBedo Mmm, I see. But we I want to do is to be able to update the pictures without having to add Urls, I don't know if you see what I mean